# Editable TableTreeView, how to cancel edit

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have made an editable TreeTableView. I want to offer editable feature based on row contents.

```
final TreeTableColumn<XXX, String> col = new TreeTableColumn<>( "Title" );
col.setCellValueFactory( new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<XXX, String >( "name"));
col.setCellFactory( TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn());
col.setOnEditStart( e -> {
   final XXX x = e.getRowValue().getValue();
   if( ! x.isEditable()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException();
   }
   e.consume();
});
```

This solution works well but I prefer to call [Cell.cancelEdit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#cancelEdit%28%29) but I don't find how without overriding a lot of classes.

I hope a simple instruction (or two) do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Cells already have an [`editable` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#editableProperty), so you can just call `setEditable(...)` on the cell as needed:

```
Callback<TreeTableColumn<XXX, String>, TreeTableCell<XXX, String>> defaultCellFactory = TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn() ;
col.setCellFactory(c -> {
    TreeTableCell<XXX, String> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(c);
    cell.indexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
        if (newIndex.intValue() >= 0 ) {
            TreeItem<XXX> item = cell.getTreeTable().getTreeItems(newIndex.intValue());
            boolean canEdit = /* logic depending on item */
            cell.setEditable(canEdit);
        } else {
            cell.setEditable(false);
        }
    });
    return cell ;
});
```

Your logic may vary depending on exactly what you want to do, e.g. you might use bindings instead of the listener on the `indexProperty`, or a listener on the `itemProperty()`, or possibly something more sophisticated, but this general structure should work.

Here's a complete example. `TreeItem`s containing `Employee`s have an editable `name` column, `TreeItem`s containing `Department`s don't:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TreeItemPropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class TreeTableCustomEditable extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


        TreeItem<Object> root = new TreeItem<>();
        TreeItem<Object> it = new TreeItem<>(new Department("IT"));
        TreeItem<Object> management = new TreeItem<>(new Department("Management"));
        TreeItem<Object> bill = new TreeItem<>(new Employee("1", "Bill Gates"));
        TreeItem<Object> tim = new TreeItem<>(new Employee("2", "Tim Cook"));
        TreeItem<Object> larry = new TreeItem<>(new Employee("3", "Larry Ellison"));
        TreeItem<Object> larryP = new TreeItem<>(new Employee("4", "Larry Page"));

        it.getChildren().addAll(larry, larryP);
        management.getChildren().addAll(bill, tim);
        root.getChildren().addAll(it, management);

        TreeTableView<Object> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();
        treeTableView.setEditable(true);
        treeTableView.setRoot(root);
        treeTableView.setShowRoot(false);

        TreeTableColumn<Object, String> idCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("ID");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Object, String>("id"));
        TreeTableColumn<Object, String> nameCol = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<Object, String>("name"));

        Callback<TreeTableColumn<Object, String>, TreeTableCell<Object, String>> defaultCellFactory = TextFieldTreeTableCell.forTreeTableColumn() ;
        nameCol.setCellFactory(c -> {
            TreeTableCell<Object, String> cell = defaultCellFactory.call(c);
            cell.indexProperty().addListener((obs, oldIndex, newIndex) -> {
                if (newIndex.intValue() >= 0) {
                    TreeItem<Object> item = cell.getTreeTableView().getTreeItem(newIndex.intValue());
                    boolean canEdit = item != null && item.getValue() instanceof Employee ;
                    cell.setEditable(canEdit);
                } else {
                    cell.setEditable(false);
                }
            });
            return cell ;
        });

        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(idCol, nameCol);
        BorderPane uiRoot = new BorderPane(treeTableView);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(uiRoot, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static class Employee {
        private final StringProperty id = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Employee(String id, String name) {
            setId(id);
            setName(name);
        }

        public final StringProperty idProperty() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getId() {
            return this.idProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setId(final java.lang.String id) {
            this.idProperty().set(id);
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setName(final java.lang.String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


    }

    public static class Department {
        private final StringProperty id = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Department(String id) {
            setId(id);
        }

        public final StringProperty idProperty() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getId() {
            return this.idProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setId(final java.lang.String id) {
            this.idProperty().set(id);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution but not in one instruction nor two... :-(

Explicit feature:

```
public interface IEditable {

   public boolean isEditable();
}
```

Using feature in a `TextFieldTreeTableCell`:

```
final class EditableTextFieldTreeTableCell<S extends IEditable>
   extends TextFieldTreeTableCell<S, String>
{
   public static <S extends IEditable>
   Callback<TreeTableColumn<S,String>, TreeTableCell<S,String>> getCallback() {
      return list -> new EditableTextFieldTreeTableCell<>( new DefaultStringConverter());
   }

   public EditableTextFieldTreeTableCell( StringConverter<String> converter ) {
      super( converter );
   }

   @Override
   public void startEdit() {
      setEditable( getTreeTableRow().getItem().isEditable());
      super.startEdit();
   }
}
```

Using the new specialized Cell class in the main:

```
final TreeTableColumn<XXX, String> col = new TreeTableColumn<>( "Title" );
col.setCellValueFactory( new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<XXX, String >( "name"));
col.setCellFactory( EditableTextFieldTreeTableCell.getCallback());
```